# What version of an npm library is *actually* used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I know that npm libraries, when installed, can install multiple versions of the same library in a hierarchical tree, like this:

```
a@0.1.0
  -> b@1.0
  -> c@2.0
       -> b@2.0
```

In the above, package `a` at version `0.1.0` is pulled in, and its dependencies `b@1.0` and `c@2.0`. Similarly, `c@2.0`'s dependency is
pulled in, which is `b@2.0`.

I have heard from someone that, even though package `b` is installed at two different versions, only one of them is actually loaded into memory and used. I have also heard that this may or may not be the case for node deployments of javascript versus browser deployments.

So my question is: Is it true that only one package of `b` is loaded into memory? If it is, is this true for both node and browser, or are there differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Nodejs

Multiple versions of a Node module/library can be loaded, depending on where they are loaded from. The [module loader is covered in depth in the Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) documentation.

The `require()` call [caches modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) based on the resolved file path.

`require('b')` from module `a` will resolve to `.../a/node_modules/b`

`require('b')` from module `c` will resolve to `.../a/node_modules/c/node_modules/b`

So seperate modules will be loaded for the same call. This can be demonstrated with a small example.

Module B - `node_modules/b/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  VERSION = 'b-0.5.0'
}
```

Module C - `node_modules/c/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  VERSION: 'c-1.0.0',
  BVERSION: require('b').VERSION,
}
```

Module C's copy of B - `node_modules/c/node_modules/b/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  VERSION: 'b-9.8.7',
}
```

Create a program to output the versions.

```
console.log('b', require('b').VERSION)
console.log('c', require('c').VERSION)
console.log('cb', require('c').BVERSION)
```

Then output the versions

```
→node index.js 
b b-0.5.0
c c-1.0.0
cb b-9.8.7
```

So two modules with different paths using `require('b').VERSION` get a different value.

#### Traversal

It's worth noting that if a Node.js `require('b')` fails to find a locally installed `./node_modules/b` then it will traverse up the directory tree to look for `b` in parent `node_modules` directories.

Using the above example case again, but removing `a/node_modules/c/node_modules/b`.

Module `c` does a `require('b')` but can't find `...a/node_modules/c/node_modules/b` then it will go into the parent `node_modules/` and look for `b`, In this case it would load the cached copy of `...a/node_modules/b`

```
→node index.js 
b b-0.5.0
c c-1.0.0
cb b-0.5.0
```

### Browser

Browsers have no concept of an npm module. You need a loader that supports CommonJS module's like Browserify or Webpack.  If the loader doesn't respect CommonJS/Node.js rules then it's unlikely to work with npm packages.

You should be able to package up the above example with your loader and see how it behaves.